# Java FTPClient listing or retrieving file is working from Windows not working from Linux - hanging at listFiles()

Tags: java, linux, ftp-client

```
ftp.connect(host, 21);
System.out.println("successfull connected");
ftp.login(user, pass);
ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(dirPath);
System.out.println("successfull logged in");

FTPFile[] listFiles =null;
// listing files from the direcotry
try {
    System.out.println("Fetching files from the directory");
    listFiles = ftp.listFiles();
}catch(Exception exception) {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = exception.getStackTrace();
    System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
    for(int i=0; i<=stackTrace.length-1; i++) {
            System.out.println(""+stackTrace[i]);
    }
}
```

I am connecting and logging to FTP server from Windows and Linux machine. On Windows, it's working well. I am able to list the FTP files. However, from Linux it is hanging at `ftp.listFiles()`, and I'm getting Accept timed out error

Please help me out or if any alternative to ftp client is also fine.

Comment: Can you explain wich ftp library you are using ? Also please provide the full error log if possible

Comment: commons-net 3.3 is the library, The flow keeps on hanging at listFiles = ftp.listFiles(), basically its timeout error from linux system.

Comment: I suggest you to try the following : disable your linux firewall just for the test : `systemctl stop iptables` or `systemctl stop firewalld` (depends of your distrib). If you are on a graphical environment, try using tierce app like Filezilla to see if this is Java related.

Comment: ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode() resolved my issue.